# Generating and Verifying Digital Certificates in J2ME Environment

Tags: authentication, java-me, x509certificate, public-key, digital-certificate

I developed a secure SMS-exchange application that uses RSA (1024-bit) for session key exchange and Twofish (128bit) for SMS encryption. I used Bouncy Castle API. At this point, I need the application to be able to verify (other) users’ public key. I want this done by verification of users’ X. 509 digital certificate as in regular PKI. How do I go about generating an X.509 digital certificate that can be used on mobile phones (on the j2me application)?